# Ошибка при установке numba

Tags: python, pip, install, numba

Пишу в командную консоль: `pip install numba`

Но почему-то выдает такую ошибку, не могу понять в чем дело, Visual Stubio стоит последний и все к нему драйвера:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\musix\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m2_iwcks\\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\musix\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m2_iwcks\\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w_b7naza\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\llvmlite'
         cwd: C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2_iwcks\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    running install
    running build
    got version from file C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2_iwcks\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.34.0', 'full': 'c5889c9e98c6b19d5d85ebdd982d64a03931f8e2'}
    running build_ext
    c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2_iwcks\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\ffi\build.py
    Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2_iwcks\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\ffi\build.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2_iwcks\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\ffi\build.py", line 179, in main
        main_win32()
      File "C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2_iwcks\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\ffi\build.py", line 88, in main_win32
        generator = find_win32_generator()
      File "C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2_iwcks\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\ffi\build.py", line 76, in find_win32_generator
        try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
      File "C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m2_iwcks\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
      File "c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
    error: command 'c:\\users\\musix\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\musix\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m2_iwcks\\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\musix\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m2_iwcks\\llvmlite_b3cf5be956a8463a8b756702ce3bd223\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w_b7naza\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\musix\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\llvmlite' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/numba/ Python versions: 3.6-3.8 а у вас питон 3.9 , попробуйте поставить версию пониже

Comment: http://numba.pydata.org/ Numba supports Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.7  а на их сайте версии ещё ниже поддерживаются...

Comment: Я установил более старую версию Python, 2.7 и 3.7.9, прописываю так же `pip install numba` и все равно так же вылезает эта же ошибка, может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Разобрался, при установке пакета ввел версию 3.7: `py -3.7 -m pip install numba`